# How should we reverse format & extract a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Pretty sure we all do `string.format` and define some string in a specifed format.

I have a string which is always formatted in a way like this:

`const string myString = string.Format("pt:{0}-first:{1}", inputString);`

To get `{0}`, I can always check for `pt:{` and read till `}`.

But what is the best/recommended way to extract {0} & {1} from the above variable `myString` ?

Comment: Are you saying after it has been formatted? That would depend a lot on the value of "inputString" as well as the expected/valid characters of that string.

Comment: By `reverse format` you mean *parse* the string? You can use a regular expression.

Comment: I would go with regex, you could possibly even generate the regex from your original format string!  (I'm at work, can't spend time on it atm).  The problem comes when your inserted strings are empty, or contains the strings that are between the inserts...

Comment: @ShawnLehner: Yes, after formatting. Let's assume the value of `myString` never changes after initial definition.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Since we always know that the value of `myString` is never going to change & is constant, and we already know which format it is going to be, what is the best way to retrieve the `{0}` part here ? I wonder if there is any inbuilt method where we can define a format & get `{0}` ?

Comment: Thinking about this more - It's not always possible.  If you inserted "pt:-first" into the string at {0} and also {1}, no amount of regex will save you.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. *why* are you trying to avoid it? That string isn't constant. The "fixed" parts aren't simple. A regex could be as simple as `"pt:(?<one>.+?)-first:(?<two>.+)"`, returning the elements as two named groups

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. if you don't want a reges you can write your own parser that reads characters and checks whether the fixed strings are encountered. You haven't mentioned what the `{0}` and `{1}` placeholders may contain. If it's "anything except the fixed parts" parsing becomes harder

Comment: `const string myString = string.Format( ... )` doesn't compile. `var inputString = "input"; string.Format("pt:{0}-first:{1}", inputString);` throws a FormatException. So what's actually in myString?

Comment: As this is not generally possible that whole idea should be dropped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Regex version of answer, but again, assuming your input doesnt contain '-'

```
var example = = "pt:hello-first:23";
var str = "pt:(?<First>[^-]+)-first:(?<Second>[^%]+)";
var match = new Regex(str).Match(example);
var first = match.Groups["First"].Value;
var second = match.Groups["Second"].Value;
```

It might be a good idea that you define what your variable can/cannot contain.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it's the most obvious:

```
string example = "pt:123-first:456";
var split = example.Split('-');

var pt = split[0].Substring(split[0].IndexOf(':') + 1);
var first = split[1].Substring(split[1].IndexOf(':') + 1);
```

As Shawn said, if you can guarantee that the variables wont contain either `:` or `-` this will be adequate.

Comment: It is important to note that this assumes inputString will never contain a - or : character and should be enforced elsewhere in your code.